# Haskell binary tree with values only in leaves

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

I would like to create a data type which represents a binary tree which has the values stored only in the leaves, then a function `sub` to check if a tree is subtree of other tree.
Here is my code, but I got no idea how to implement the function `sub`.

```
data BinaryTree a = Leaf a | Node (BinaryTree a) (BinaryTree a)  deriving Show

makeBinTree :: [a] -> BinaryTree a
makeBinTree lst = head $ mrg leaves
where
  leaves = map (\x -> Leaf x) lst
  mrg [] = []
  mrg [x] = [x]
  mrg (x:y:xs) = mrg ( (Node x y) : mrg xs)

sub :: Eq a => BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a -> Bool
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need a function to see if two trees are equal. You can derive `Eq` or implement something recursively like this

```
eq :: Eq a => BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a -> Bool
eq (Leaf x) (Leaf y) = x == y
eq (Node l1 r1) (Node l2 r2) = (l1 `eq` l2) && (r1 `eq` r2)
eq _ _ = False
```

With that you can do

```
sub :: Eq a => BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a -> Bool
sub s (Leaf y) = s `eq` Leaf y
sub s t@(Node l r) = s `eq` t || sub s l || sub s r
```

The first tree is a sub-tree of the second if both are equal or it is a sub-tree of the left or the right sub-tree.

Comment: Word of warning: This is probably quite inefficient. I'm not sure if there is a more efficient way or not.